# Colored Curly Brackets spanning across multiple pages

Tags: color, page-breaking, brackets

This is just a thought that came for the notes I am working on, 
**I have a need to create curly brackets which span across multiple pages.**

[image]
I don't know if this is possible to do or not. 
my curly bracket knowledge is limited to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: you might need to draw a picture of what you mean. Do you mean a normal sized { on one page and a normal sized } on a later page, or do you want some kind of extra large { surrounding multiple paragraphs or....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - To the question I added an image. I created this in MS word and it has a limitation of one page. It does not span across pages.

Answer (score 5):

Spacing's not perfect and it's using a full brace in both halves rather than some kind of half brace but it might get you started.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{.4\textheight}

\usepackage{color,graphicx}

\newcounter{setc}
\newcounter{subsetc}[setc]

\newenvironment{subsetlist}
{\par\addvspace\bigskipamount\delimitershortfall-1em
\refstepcounter{subsetc}%
\noindent$\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{red} Subset -- \thesubsetc}}\color{green}\left\{\color{black}\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}\itemize}
{\enditemize\end{minipage}\right.$%
\par\addvspace\bigskipamount}



%\noindent$\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{red} Set -- \thesubsetc}}\color{green}\left\{\color{black}\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}\itemize}

\newenvironment{setlist}
{\par\mbox{}\par
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\hsize.7\textwidth
\refstepcounter{setc}}%
{\egroup
\ifdim\ht0>\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
\setbox2\vsplit0 to \dimexpr 0.7\pagegoal-0.7\pagetotal\relax
\noindent$\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{red} Set -- \thesetc\ \ldots}}\color{green}%
\left\{\color{black}\vcenter{\box2}\right.$%
\par
\noindent$\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{red}\ldots\  Set -- \thesetc}}\color{green}\left\{\color{black}\vcenter{\box0}\right.$%
\else
\noindent$\mathop{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{red}\ldots\  Set -- \thesetc}}\color{green}\left\{\color{black}\vcenter{\box0}\right.$%
\fi
}


\begin{document}


\begin{setlist}

\begin{subsetlist}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc
\end{subsetlist}

\begin{subsetlist}
\item aaa
\item ccc
\item bbb
\end{subsetlist}

\begin{subsetlist}
\item aaa
\item ccc
\item bbb
\end{subsetlist}

\begin{subsetlist}
\item aaa
\item ccc
\item bbb
\end{subsetlist}

\begin{subsetlist}
\item aaa
\item ccc
\item bbb
\end{subsetlist}

\end{setlist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it works great but has a one page limitation. if I increase the number of rows in it. It reduces the font size and tries to fit to a page. would be nice if there was a way to introduce a page break. I tried using array in Math mode and it does the same thing as well.

Comment: No it never changes font size and as the example output shows it will split over a page (it only does one page break as written) It doesn't split the subsets but will split the outer set list over a page (and does in the posted example)

Comment: array will never change the font size to squeeze more on the page, it simply does not have that information available (page breaking happens later) whatever you are seeing is not caused by what you think is causing it.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how would I add more page breaks. You said it is written for one page break only.

Comment: where I have the vsplit you would need to loop keep vsplitting off more until the remaining bit was less than a page. No time to do that at work, I may later or someone else may

Comment: Dear David, I am sure this code can modified to draw the curly braces, _on the right_, spanning two or more items. But I am having difficulty parsing the code, may you please add some comments to the code? Thank you. :)

Comment: @KannappanSampath OK but not tonight, too late:-)

Comment: @David Sure thing. Take your time. I'll check back after a day or so. :)

Comment: @Davind- Can you please show me how use vsplit so that I can span it across multiple pages. I would appreciate your help.