# braces marks with \framed & \tikz

Tags: margins, mdframed, tikz-styles, delimiters

I'm trying to mark some paragraphs with boxes, braces, brackets or parentheses coupled with notes in margin… My first test was using `\makebox` & `minipage` according to [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33993/brace-and-text-in-side-margin) as you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128034/make-a-command-to-mark-a-text-and-class-them-for-text-analyze) & after in my code: `\accoladedroite` & `\crochetdroit` commands. But, you know, it makes problems to split across pages.

So, I want to use `\mdframed`, better for this job. I'm now learning `\mdframed` & `\tikz` (my teachers are `\mdframed` manuals & exemples, & reference discussions with @Peter_Grill [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37245/environments-for-visually-setting-text-apart?lq=1) & [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70436/enclose-an-entry-in-an-enumerate-list-in-parentheses/73307#73307) and @Gonzalo_Medina [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158649/deep-brackets-around-a-text/158650#158650)). My questions :

- How to put a beautiful typographic curly brace all the distance of the box, like in musical score, for example `\}` in the innerline right of `\mdframed` ?
- How to add some texte or title in front of the brace center, in margin ?
- How to repeat these titles, why not, with dots in the first… - …middle… & …second box (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74995/colored-curly-brackets-spanning-across-multiple-pages/75002#comment160210_75002)) ?

Thats my code :

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = arara
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv[hidealllines=true,
    singleextra={
        \draw;
        \draw([xshift=-0.1cm]P) -- (P) -- (P|-O) -- ([xshift=-0.1cm]P|-O);},
    firstextra={
        \draw;
        \draw([xshift=-0.1cm]P) -- (P) -- (P|-O);},
    middleextra={
        \draw;
        \draw(P) -- (P|-O);},
    secondextra={
        \draw;
        \draw(P) -- (P|-O) -- ([xshift=-0.1cm]P|-O);},
    ]{mybox}

\newcommand\accoladedroite[3]
    {\par
    \smallskip
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]
        {$\left.
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}
        \right\}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{gray}#2}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{ }
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}$}
    \par
    \smallskip}

\newcommand\crochetdroit[3]
    {\par
    \smallskip
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]
        {$\left.
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}
        \right]
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\color{gray}#2}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}$}
    \par
    \smallskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\accoladedroite{Titre 1}{Titre 1.1}{\lipsum[2]}
\crochetdroit{Titre 2}{Titre 2.1}{\lipsum[3]}
\begin{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
% arara: xelatex
```

And the result :

[image: screenshot]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see where you are using `mdframed` except for the fact that you load it so I'm not sure what problem you are experiencing in using it.

Comment: @cfr in my `\newmdenv` I presume…